# Combine [AND], [OR] conditions in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a beautiful URL for my site now I'm focusing on extensionless URL but in order for success form submission I need to disable the **forcing extensionless URL** function for specified file, now I want to disable the function for two file

And also I know there is some question like this that says or have higher priority than and but my code is still not working my redirect checker still says I post to receive.php than redirect to receive which made the value doesn't pass correctly

Here is my code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !status.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !verify.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=301,L]
```

So my case I want to for extensionless URL except for my status.php and verify.php file

Comment: You dont need the OR flag, Replace your OR with AND.

Comment: So if I remove my or tag the code should work?

Comment: I am sorry, AND flag isnt supported in apache. Apache uses AND as default if no flags are specified. You need to remove your flags.

Comment: I think I got the point my condition is base on that if the file is not those two file it should rewrite thanks a lot I'm confusing on the point that I want it to rewrite if it is not that two file not if it was those two file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have misunderstood the goal I want to achive
I can use `[AND]` or add nothing to the `RewriteCond` line
because I'm using AND condition so If i visit verify.php and status.php they won't rewrite